# Unable to display stories in Storybook using native Svelte .svelte files

Tags: svelte, storybook

I'm trying to implement a story using Storybook and Svelte, which uses three components - Grid, Row and Column. The actual components came from https://github.com/MarieanneWU20/svelte-grid-layout - I've saved copies locally into my project.

This is the code I have for my story - it seems to be the only format I can get a template set up as shown below:

`Grid.stories.svelte:`

```
<script>
  // @ts-ignore
  import { Meta, Template, Story } from "@storybook/addon-svelte-csf";
  import Grid from "../Grid/Grid.svelte";
  import Row from "../Grid/Row.svelte";
  import Column from "../Grid/Column.svelte";
</script>

<Meta title="Grid" component={Grid} />

<Template let:args id="Default">
  <svelte:fragment slot="gridlayout">
    <Grid {...args}>
      <Row {...args}>
        <Column height="1" width="4">
          <header>
            <h2>Description</h2>
          </header>
          <hr />
          <p>
            <span class="bold">Svelte Grid Layout</span> is a tool that make it easier
            to create a page template for applications built with Svelte
          </p>
        </Column>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  </svelte:fragment>
</Template>

<Story name="Default" template="Default" />
```

However, I'm having trouble with figuring out why I'm getting this error in Storybook, and why it doesn't display a story for Grid:

```
Cannot process .svelte file with storyStoreV7: src/lib/storybook/Grid.stories.svelte
```

I've found an issue logged on the Storybook GitHub site at https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/16673, which says the current workaround is to disable storyStoreV7 in the SB config, and to add `"@storybook/addon-svelte-csf"` into the list of plugins. I've tried this - it didn't seem to have any effect; adding the plugin seemed to have an impact on one of my other plugins!

I've checked through the Storybook documentation for Svelte, and have tried various combinations based on those at https://storybook.js.org/docs/svelte/writing-stories/stories-for-multiple-components, but with no success (and which throws up all manner of errors!)

I've also checked through StackOverflow, but so far not found anything that relates to this issue.

I would like to be able to use the Grid components in Storybook if possible, but am stuck on how to add them in - can anyone please help?

Config:

- Storybook: 6.5.9
- Svelte: 3.49.0
- Storybook `.stories` files: written in Markdown (preferred), but happy to consider .js or .svelte format if there is a solution.